# No consigo hacer post del devicetoken

Tags: ios, swift

He configurado las notificaciones utilizando GCM y para posteriormente poder enviarlas, necesito registrar los tokens en mi base de datos. En primer lugar en mi AppDelegate, almaceno el token de la siguiente forma:

```
let deviceTokenString = NSString(format: "%@", deviceToken) as String

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(deviceTokenString, forKey: "deviceToken")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Después de esto, en otra pantalla realizo un Post que he comprobado que funciona puesto que un valor determinado o incluso otra variable se publica sin ningún problema, pero el token no lo hace. Por ejemplo, en este código, la variable `otra` se publicaría pero `tokenstring` no lo hace.

```
var tokenstring = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("deviceToken")
var otra = "prueba"
...

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/post/registrar-ios.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let token = "token=\(self.tokenstring)&so=ios"

        request.HTTPBody = token.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
```

Por otro lado, he creado una función para poder ver el valor almacenado en ese valor de `NSUserDefaults` y se muestra el token por lo que el fallo tampoco debería estar ahí. ¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: ¿Has comprobado lo que le llega al servidor?

Comment: En caso de hacer post con el token, aparece nada en el json que me carga lo registrado en la bd. En cualquier otro caso sí

Comment: Es que tengo dudas de que el body se lo debas pasar así...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de ver tu fichero, te recomiendo que utilices directamente `Alamofire` tal que así:

```
func showAlert(title:String, message:String) {


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .Default, handler:{  action in

        Alamofire.request(
            .POST,
            "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/post/registrar-ios.php",
            parameters: ["token": \(self.tokenstring), "so": "ios"]
            ).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in

                // Tratar las respuesta

            })

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("inicial", sender: self)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "TermsAccepted")

    })

    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.33, green:0.0, blue:0.34, alpha:1.0)

    alert.addAction(acceptAction)


    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);

    self.prueba.text = message


}
```

Comment: Perfecto, lo único para gente con dudas similares añade `\(self.tokenstring)`. Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Pasar el `body` como si fueran datos de parámetros de `URL` no me da buena espina.
Prueba la variante siguiente:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/post/registrar-ios.php?token=\(self.tokenstring)&so=ios")!)
```

A ver si de esta forma te llega al servidor ni que sea...

Por otro lado, si pasas los datos por el `body`, lo que tienes que hacer es un `POST` y deberías cambiar el formato con lo que lo pasas, por ejemplo a `JSON`
Puedes probar por hacer la `request` tal que así:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/post/registrar-ios.php")!)
request.encodeParameters(["token": self.tokenstring, "so": "ios"])
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

Y después lanzar el `POST`.

En cualquier caso, es difícil ver que está pasando sin poder ver lo que envías, recibes, etc.

Comment: Voy a probar! Pero antes de todo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo he probado y disculpa pero soy nuevo en esto... En el primer caso no sé si debo sustituir mi línea equivalente a esa por eso y dejar el resto igual o cambiar algo más y en el segundo caso tengo error en iOS por `unresolved identifier`

Comment: En el segundo caso ¿en qué línea te da ese error?

Comment: En la que se enviarían los valores según entiendo yo... Donde pone `"so" : ios`

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar, me dejé unas comillas

Comment: Sigue habiendo un error, dice `Value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' has no member 'encodeParameters'`

Comment: ¿podrías crear un proyecto con todo el código que te falla? Será más fácil que te lo corrija, que no estar así...

Comment: Aquí está el archivo conflictivo en cuestión https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqv37ssk113k448/ViewController.swift?dl=0 con tu código ya añadido